# how to create a regex to check for a decimal(11,5)

Tags: regex

How do i create a regex to check if a a user input is matching a datatype?
ex: decimal(11,5) restrictions:

- 1-6 digits before decimal separator
- 0-5 digits after decimal separator
- decimal separator is optional

.

```
^[0-9]{1,6}([,\\.][0-9]{0,5})$
```

--> is not working, but i don't know why.

Seems like i also get a match when typing `1234567` when there are just 6 digits allowed before the optional decimal separator...

Can anyone point me to my mistake?
(i'm new to regex :-))

Comment: Works fine: http://regex101.com/r/vL4dN6

Comment: Why do you say it isn't working?  What data fails to pass correctly?

Comment: `^[0-9]{1,6}(?:[,.][0-9]{0,5})?$`

Comment: Why are the decimal numbers and decimal-point in a capture group, but not the whole number?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a tricky business - to fix your problem add non-capturing groups like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match("123456.123456" + Environment.NewLine, @"(?:[^,\.0-9]?)([0-9]{1,6}([,\\.][0-9]{1,5})?)(?:[^,\\.0-9])");
```

The non-capturing Group `(?:[^,\.0-9]?)` tells Regex not to match any of the characters between the square brackets.